# Axis2 object to xml

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, apache-axis

I have an Axis2 Object returned from my Java code. How can I convert that object to XML or output it as XML in the console? I know there is lots of 3rd party libraries available to serialize objects to XML - but how to do it with the Axis2?

---

**Update:** From [this link](http://wso2.org/library/2068) I found the solution. One needs to get an `OMElement` like this:

```
OMElement omElement = sampleElement1
          .getOMElement(SampleElement1.MY_QNAME, OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory()); 
String omElementString = omElement.toStringWithConsume();
System.out.println("XML String ==> " + omElementString);
```

Comment: I referred this URL : wso2.org/library/2068 ... and i found the solution ..... we need to get OMElement using the getOMElement method OMElement omElement = sampleElement1.getOMElement(SampleElement1.MY_QNAME, OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory()); String omElementString = omElement.toStringWithConsume(); System.out.println("XML String ==> " + omElementString);

Answer (score 2):

Just call `yourObject.toString()` on `OMElement`